# Model a fixed list of options: enum, class or constants?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I'm using ASP.NET and EntityFramework and am trying to model a class "car" that has a property "category" where category is just a string from a fixed list of options, e.g. "new car", "oldtimer". I would like to display all available categories in a dropdown. I am not sure how to model this:

**enum**: category is a string, so I guess enums don't work here, though they would be perfect for a dropdown

**constants**: would be good for strings, but inconvenient to create a drop down from

**class** with property "name": seems convenient

Is it best practice to use an extra class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use an extra class to model the category. With enums and constants you may have some trouble when doing queries as they cannot be used directly when using linq, for instance.